# Bootstrap - table inside card does not fit

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a bootstrap table inside a card but it does not fit into it.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
   <div class="card-columns d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let test of tests">
        <div class="card-header">
            <strong>
                test
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let rule of test.rules; let i = index">
            <table class="table table-striped text-center">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong>IDs</strong>
                        <button type="button" class="no-border btn-link-clear">
                            <i class="fa fa-change "></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let id of rule.ids">
                    <td >
                        {{ id }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the css of the component?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div class="card-columns d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let test of tests">
        <div class="card-header">
            <strong>
                test
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let rule of test.rules; let i = index">
            <table class="card-table table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>2222.2.2.9822.2.2.2.2.787po4878957iowr2.2.2.2.2.2.22222222.2.2.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>2222.248573945.2.22.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.22222222.2.2.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Larry</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[I have also add a snap of the output. Hope this is helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zia5P.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card-body overflow-auto" *ngFor="let rule of test.rules; let i = index">
```

`overflow-auto` here prevents content from overflowing outside the container element. Same can be achieved by adding style `overflow: auto;` to the container element.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).